# Acceder a un Array al mandar un mail - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo el registro de una página y cuando se registran cabe la posibilidad de que tengan que mandar un adjunto en el mail. Entonces quiero acceder al nombre del archivo que tengo en el sistema y enviarlo.

```
     if($request->hasFile('modelos')) {
        $model = $data['modelos'];
        $extension = $model->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $model_name  = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $model->move(base_path('public/images/modelos/'), $model_name);

        return User::create([

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'tipo_id' => 3,
            'cif' => $data['cif'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'apellidos' => $data['apellidos'],
            'slug' => $slug,
            'pais' => $data['pais'],         
            'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'empresa' => $data['empresa'],
            'codigo' => $data['codigo'],
            'modelo' => $model_name,

            Mail::to('email@gmail.com')->send(new Cliente($data)),
        ]);
```

Luego en el modelo del mail:

```
public $subject = 'High As - Nuevo cliente';

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->modelo = $data['modelos'][1];

    }
```

Si hago un `dd($data);` recibo esto:

```
array:14 [▼
  "_token" => "q3kDN6rspXlU6FeswQNXsQtvWuPbF1qTItjx3weB"
  "email" => "sip@gmail.com"
  "password" => ""
  "password_confirmation" => ""
  "name" => ""
  "apellidos" => ""
  "cif" => ""
  "telefono" => ""
  "pais" => "AI"
  "inlineRadioOptions" => "tienda"
  "empresa" => "Mi tienda"
  "codigo" => "KUrQFfQn4n"
  "letrasEmail" => "sip"
  "modelos" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#387 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "mitades.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "phpXxUkxq"
    basename: "phpXxUkxq"
    pathname: "/tmp/phpXxUkxq"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/phpXxUkxq"
    aTime: 2020-11-17 09:11:17
    mTime: 2020-11-17 09:11:17
    cTime: 2020-11-17 09:11:17
    inode: 7818
    size: 952639
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 33
    group: 33
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

Quiero acceder a sacar el nombre que trae modelos `-originalName: "mitades.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Publico mi respuesta, por si le puede interesar a alguien en un futuro. Podemos extraer el dato con `get`.

```
$this->modelo= $data['modelos']->getClientOriginalName();
```